# Markov's inequality, unclear Wikipedia intuition

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, means

Search for the word "intuitive" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality). I do not understand how

$$E[X]=0\cdot \bar{a}+\frac{E[X]}{a}\cdot a$$

shows anything at all. I would like to see an intuitive proof of an upper bound of $P(x\geq a)$ which should be $$P(x\geq a)\leq \frac{E[X]}{a}.$$

Comment: [This "intuitive proof" section comes from a recent set of edits by a single editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Markov%27s_inequality&type=revision&diff=831693627&oldid=830734174).  If you think the section is wrong, Wikipedia can be editied

Comment: My intuition says (for a non-negative random variable) that $\mathbb E[X\mid X\ge a] \ge a$ and $\mathbb E[X\mid X\lt a] \ge 0$ so  $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[X\mid X\ge a]\mathbb P(X \ge a)+\mathbb E[X\mid X\lt a]\mathbb P(X \lt a) \ge a\mathbb P(X\ge a)+0\mathbb P(X\lt a)$ giving the inequality

Comment: That seems correct. And could you modify your argument for the increasing $\varphi$ to see that $P(|X|\geq a)\leq \frac{E[\varphi(X)]}{\varphi(a)}$?

Answer (score 0):

For an increasing $\varphi$, $X\geq a \implies \varphi(X)\geq\varphi(a)$. Thus you can construct a similar argument. However, remember it is important to have $X$ a non-negative random variable in the original argument and thus if we are to replicate the argument the image of $\varphi$ should be non-negative.

Note that what you request, i.e.

$$P(|X|\geq a)\leq \frac{E[\varphi(X)]}{\varphi(a)}$$

can not be true in general. Take $X\sim N(0,1)$, $a=1$ and $\varphi$ the identity.